# Реализовать сохранение и открытие сохраненного файла в проекте

Tags: c#, wpf

Можно ли сохранить массив объектов, в отдельный файл, а потом запустить этот файл в приложении и восстановить массив (который был в файле) из этого файла ? (Знаю что можно, но как сделать)

Comment: Использовать сериализацию/десериализацию.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можно пример

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала давайте поймем, что же такое сериализация/десериализация:

> **Сериализация** (в программировании) (англ. serialization) — процесс перевода какой-либо структуры данных в последовательность битов. Обратной к операции сериализации является операция **десериализации** (структуризации) (англ. deserialization) — восстановление начального состояния структуры данных из битовой последовательности.

*Источник: [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).*

Последовательность байтов мы смело можем заменить на любой, удобный для нас вид (XML, JSON и др.). Я лично обожаю JSON и по этому в примерах буду использовать его.

---

Допустим у нас есть некая коллекция `Names`, которая содержит в себе некие объекты:

```
List<string> Names = new List<string>
{
    "Вася", "Петя", "Маша", "Аня"
};
```

Нам надо ее сериализовать в удобный нам вид и сохранить в файл:
**Как я уже говорил, буду использовать JSON, а с ним очень легко работать при помощи библиотеки `Newtonsoft.Json` (устанавливаем через NuGet).*

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Names);
File.WriteAllText("MyData.json", jsonString);
```

После этого у нас будет создан файл `MyData.json`, который будет содержать внутри себя наш сериализованный объект в JSON формате:

```
["Вася","Петя","Маша","Аня"]
```

Теперь делаем обратное, вытягиваем данные из файла, десерилизируем и получаем обратно `List<string>`:

```
var file = File.ReadAllText("MyData.json");
List<string> Names = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(file);
```

---

Вот собственно и все, такими простыми действиями мы "загоняем" данные в файл и в дальнейшем читаем его. Формат, а также объект могут быть разными, это уже как вам заучиться и что удобней.
Вобщем удачи в изучении C#!